# [Error]TypeError :expected dynamic type 'double',but had type string in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, stylesheet

Currently getting an error when ever clicking on a react TouchableOpacity control.

[image]

Comment: Nice screenshot. But, what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix by removing the transform from StyleSheet.

```
 transform: [
      {
        rotate: '45deg'
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. I was stuck with this error from a week.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<TouchableHighlight>` instead of `<TouchableOpacity>` will prevent the crash and you can still use the transform.